# why I get 'not a function' error in mapping array

Tags: reactjs

I have o idea why I am getting `TypeError: sheltersList.map is not a function` when it should map the array instead? What is wrong with my code? I dont understand it..

```
import React from 'react';

const SheltersList = (sheltersList) => {
    console.log(sheltersList);
    if (sheltersList.lenght != 0) {
        return (
            <div>
                { sheltersList.map(function(shelter) {
                    <option id={shelter.id}>{shelter.name}</option>
                })}
            </div>
        )
    } else { return (
        <option> loading... </option>
    )}
}

export default SheltersList;
```

Comment: it is `length` not `lenght ` and `sheltersList` is prop, so you are looking for `({ sheltersList = [] })

Comment: damn, I keep making this spelling mistake for ages now :) thanks for that. And what You mean by `{shelterList}` ? should I use it differently? Don't know how to map it now. thanks

Answer (score 1):

`map` is a function of the `Array.prototype`. It seems like the parameter `sheltersList` is not an `Array`.

Sine this is a React functional component, you might find your `sheltersList` Array from `sheltersList.sheltersList` in this case.

Comment: it is an array, I am logging it to console and I get `{sheltersList: Array(0)}`.In the conditional I am waiting for the fetch and after the array is filled it shoul populate the DOM with these elements. At least that is the plan

Comment: If that is the exact output you get, then it seems like you are logging an Object to the console instead of an Array. If that is the case, try `sheltersList.sheltersList`.

Comment: You were right about the  `sheltersList.sheltersList`, I have created `var shelters = sheltersList.sheltersList;` and now I get emty array in console from it. But it still says it is not a function and does not map it.

Comment: Perhaps an unnecessay question, but are you sure you are mapping the `shelters` variable (i.e. `shelters.map()`) so that you did not forget to change the variable name in the `return` statement? Because the `if`-clause should not be entered in case you switched the `if (sheltersList.length != 0)` to `if (shelters.length != 0)` because you have an Array of length 0.

Comment: I have changed it, it is `shelters.map()` now so that part shoud be Ok. Initially it is always an empty array since it fetches data from API, but it should re-render once the data is fetched...now that I said it, I realised I probably need this component also to read the state of the store to receive the change in the array value. Am I right?

Comment: In case the component receives data after rendering (or returning if it is a Funcional component), then yes you do need some state. The best place is probably in the component that does the API fetching.

Comment: I am using redux in this case - just learning it on this one really...Now will have to figure out how to get the state of the fetched array into this component.....thanks to all, it helped me to see it a bit clearer, even though I  am still not sure how to solve it..

Answer (score 0):

When you passing props to components by their name you should use destructuring syntax.

```
const SheltersList = ({ sheltersList }) => { // sheltersList is your list
```

Now your list is inside prop called "sheltersList". When you passed it like before your list is rather inside object named "sheltersList" which in this case should be rather named "props"

```
const SheltersList = ( sheltersList ) => { // sheltersList contains all props and your list is probably inside sheltersList.sheltersList
```

When you use destructuring you can also set default value to be sure if everything works fine when you forgot to pass sheltersList.

```
const SheltersList = ({ sheltersList = []}) => {
```